# (Firebase.exception: package not authenticated) is thrown but, the app is already connected to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, sms

My app requires 2 modes of authentication. I have already created a sign in method using Email and Password and it is working perfectly fine. My second mode of authentication uses Phone verification. I have already configured the SHA-1 key, added it to the console and updated the app with the latest google-services.json file. 
The phone verification process happens in the activity after email and password verification.

I have also tried to to link email and password credentials with phoneauth. It still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: So your app provides two options of authentication or a single authentication process with 2 steps being email/password as the first step and phone verification as second?

Comment: I'm using email/password as a single authentication step. My app requires phone verification, so I set up phoneauth as well. But I intend not to use phoneauth as a signin method but just as a verification step. (I know email verification can be used my I need phone auth)

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer provided in [Firebase Github Issues](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/214):

> We currently don't support account management in FirebaseUI. If the user logs in with a Google account and you want to add a phone number to that user. You would go through the phone verification flow, get a phoneAuthCredential and then firebase.auth().currentUser.updatePhoneNumber(phoneAuthCredential) on the user.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But I have created the phone verification flow now and the error is still thrown